# How to debug a breaking test in Travis CI?

Tags: travis-ci

I have a few tests that pass on my machine, but fail in Travis CI. Is there an easy way to debug those tests? My project is in Ruby.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reproduce a travis-ci build environment for debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753560/how-to-reproduce-a-travis-ci-build-environment-for-debugging)